# How do I click a hyper link in a web browser automatically in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, hyperlink

Let's say my browser goes to a page similar to this one below ..

[Picture Is Here](http://manuals.matrix.squizsuite.net/__images/asset-screens/metadata/keyword-replacement-click-here-link.png)

On this  page there is a hyper link called 'Click Here' ..  when I click it, it opens another window with things in it.

How can I click this hyper link in vb.net automatically without me clicking on it with the mouse, and how do I open the window in a second web browser ?

We can assume that the first browser is called (WebBroswer1 ) and the second one is called (WebBrower2).

I know how to perform buttons clicks and do raise the 'OnClick' Events, but I don't know how to do it with a hyper links.

Please any help will be appreciated, I look forward for solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have jquery available in your webpage you can do something like

Say you have Click Here

you can programatically trigger the click of that link by doing:

```
$("#webbrowser2").trigger("click");
```

HTH